# PhpStorm text size

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to define a shortcut to increase/decrease size of code in PhpStorm, like what you can do in Notepad++ with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>?

Comment: Ctrl+MouseWheel works in PhpStorm as well: **Settings | Editor | Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel**

Comment: The way you set up everything is a bit strange, I had a hard time changing the font and setting up the size of it (being shortsighted is not funny) But the black colors are a welcome addition.

Comment: ...and the official "reset" command is to hit `CTRL+SHIFT+A` and type "reset zoom".

Answer (score 193, accepted):

**Enable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>:** Settings -> Editor -> Change font size (Zoom) with  Ctrl+Mouse Wheel (check).

[image]

---

**Specify exact font size:** Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font.

[image]

Comment: For some reason it's disabled

Comment: @dVaffection you have to click `Save As..` to be able to modify the parameters.

Comment: In phpstorm 9 font size settings disabled, how to enable it?

Comment: @ymakux, go **Settings** => **Editor** => **General** => Enable **Change font size (Zoom) with Control+Mouse Wheel**

Comment: Thanks, already found it. Now using Sublime Text an Notepad++ - much simpler and faster

Comment: File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Mouse -> Enable Change font size (Zoom) with Control+Mouse Wheel

Comment: Why on earth is this not enabled by default? What were the devs thinking?!

Comment: Preferences -> Editor -> General. Under Mouse Control section, check "Change font size with Command+Mouse Wheel"

Answer (score 25):

I am able to **[change my PHP Storm](https://youtu.be/I64aMsrNoT4)** (**version 8.0.3 or later**) Fonts by

1. Go to File and then click Settings.
2. Form Left Side Menu, Select `Editor` --> `General` Tab
3. Check this box under `Mouse` section `Change font size (zoom) with Ctrl_Mouse Wheel` (see below pic).

[image]

[30 Second Demo Here](https://youtu.be/I64aMsrNoT4)

Answer (score 19):

in new version in this address
file > setting > Editor > general
check this item
Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel

Comment: yup for php storm 2019 this is the way

Answer (score 9):

Also you can use **View → Enter Presentation Mode**.

Default font size for this mode is 24.

You can change it here: *Settings → Appearance → Presentation Mode → Font size*

Comment: Ideal for thos not having a mouse :-)

Comment: One more way to switch to the presentation mode:

View → Quick Switch Scheme → View Mode → Enter Presentation Mode.

(Good choice for the shortcut funs)

Answer (score 7):

The pre-defined schemes are not editable. To change colors and fonts settings in such a scheme, create its copy. 
So to change font size select any scheme of your choice. Save the "scheme" as a copy with a name like "scheme 2".
Now the default font size will be editable.

Answer (score 7):

In MacOS, you should navigate to the PhpStorm -> Preferences -> Editor -> General screen and check/uncheck the "Change font size (Zoom) with Command + Mouse Wheel" checkbox. I unchecked because I don't like it but maybe you do.

Moreover, you can use the finder field in the top left corner of the same PhpStorm -> Preferences dialog. Type the word "size" in this field and you will see a couple of items on the right hand side of the dialog. There are the Editor Actions -> Decrease Font Size and Editor Actions -> Increase Font Size options.

Right click each of them and choose "Add Keyboard Shortcut". Finally, press the Ctrl and numerical plus in case of Increase and Ctrl and numerical minus in case of Decrease and press OK (if you have numerical part of your keyboard).

Answer (score 3):

In PhpStorm 2020.2.1 go to :

Settings -> Editor-> Font

[image]

That's it

Answer (score -1):

Switching beetween Editors and zooming text during presentations or so could be complicated.
If you used to do it like in notepad++ than maybe this helps if you use win:

```
^NumpadAdd::
    send,^{WheelUp}
return
```

the complete script you could find here: https://gist.github.com/sl5net/7170280#file-gistfile1-txt